# How do I get displayed string from one table view in another table view?

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I passed string from controllerA (second item in tab bar) to controllerB (first item in tab bar), added that string to array and want to display it. I called reloadData but table view is still empty. What I have to do to get my string displayed in controllerB? (this two controllers are connected to two different navigation controllers and I don't want to use seque).

here is some code:
    //ControllerA

```
ControllerB *bController = [[ControllerB alloc]init];
bController.myString = self.cellLabel.text;
[tableController addButtonIsPressed];

//ControllerB.h
@property (copy, readwrite) NSString *myString;

//ControllerB.m
```

-(void)addButtonIsPressed {

```
[myData addObject:@"myString"]; //in NSLog I can see correct value of myString
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

Now I realized then When I print myData in console it is null. Even if i initialize myData with values in viewDidLoad in this method its (null)..

Comment: Need a bit more information.  Is controllerB a UITableViewController or a UIViewController with a UITableView inside?  If it is the latter, make sure your delegate is wired properly.  If that is not the issue, maybe you could supply some of your UITableView's delegate method code?

Comment: @MikeS I edited my question.. Yes, both Controllers are UITableViewController.

Comment: I am trying to understand your design. How do you pass the string to `ControllerB`? Is it by the code you showed here?

Comment: @Canopus Yes. I created property myString in ControllerB, made instance of ControllerB in ControllerA and assign string i want to pass to that property. It looked a bit strange to me, but I realized it works and maybe thats why I'm in trouble now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need more information but the problem might be here :

```
ControllerB *bController = [[ControllerB alloc]init];
```

You declare **another** Controller maybe it's not the same controller who's display.
Cause i don't see any : [self displayModal  ....]
You juste create a B controller with the correct "mystring" but you're displaying another B controller.

Comment: You typed faster than I did.  :-)  I need to make a macro that inserts that kind of answer every time I see someone attempting to message one object by creating a different one of the same kind.

Comment: this question was ask 2hour ago :p
too late same with a maccro

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response, here are some thoughts. Hope it helps:

1. When you have two or more view controllers, the convention is that the parent controller talks directly to the child controller via settings its properties. However, when the child wants to talk to the parent, it does it by using delegation.

This is the same when you have two parallel controllers, as it is in your case.
They shouldn't set each others property directly. **They should use delegation.**

1. Also, is your case, the instance of `ControllerB` that you have instantiated, is not the same as the one that is on the screen. It is a new one! It is a new instance of `ControllerB` and has absolutely nothing to do with the one that is on the screen.

If you search you can find several examples of how to do delegation.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I did delegation before, but I couldn't get called method addButtonIsPressed with this line of code [self.delegate addButtonIsPressed].. ok. will try to solve this issue one more time.

Comment: My understanding is `addButtonIsPressed` is a method in `ControllerB`. Right? So, to do the delegation, `ControllerB` is actually the one who should adapt the delegation of `ControllerA`. `ControllerA` doesn't (and shouldn't) know anything about `ControllerB`. You define a delegate method in `ControllerA`; `ControllerB` adapts the protocol, and implements the method. `ControllerA` calls the delegate method, and `ControllerB` gets notified, and does what it wants to do.

Comment: thats the way I did it. Can you tell me please how ControllerA calls the delegate method? Don't understand where is my mistake..